# How to compute for the smallest distance possible?

Tags: c++

[Kattis Problem - Freckles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUnPU.png)

I'm trying to solve a hard problem in Kattis. The first test in kattis passed while the second one got a wrong answer. Don't know what's wrong with my code.

My first approach was to compute the distance in each pair of coordinates and mark them as finished if it resulted to the smallest distance. The code below is my second approach which I tried to sort first the coordinates and shorten its distance to one another sequentially. Other implementation advice would also be helpful.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <limits>
#include <cmath>
#include <list>
#include <iomanip>

double distance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2);

int main()
{
std::string input;
std::getline(std::cin, input);
int test_cases = std::stoi(input);

// Container for all the testcases
std::list< std::vector< std::pair<double, double> > > testcases;

for (int i = 0; i < test_cases; i++)
{

    //ignore blank line for each test case as instructed.
    std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );

    std::getline(std::cin, input);
    int total_coor = std::stoi( input );
    std::vector<std::pair<double, double>> coor;
    double x, y;

    for ( int i = 0; i < total_coor; i++ )
    {
        std::cin >> x >> y;
        std::pair<double, double> temp(x, y);
        coor.push_back( temp );
    }

    // Partially sort the pair elements to process the distance sequentially
    std::sort( coor.begin(), coor.end() );

    // Temporary Coordinates to further sort the coordinates via the smallest coordinate difference 
    double temp1y, temp2y, temp1x, temp2x;
   
    for ( int i = 0; i < total_coor; i++ )
    {
        int placeholder = i;
        temp1x = temp2x = temp1y = temp2y = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
        
        for (int j = i + 1; j < total_coor; j++)
        {
            temp2y = std::abs( coor[j].second - coor[i].second );
            temp2x = std::abs( coor[j].first - coor[i].first );

            // if current y diff is smaller than previous, set current position
            if ( temp2y < temp1y )
            {
                temp1y = temp2y;
                temp1x = temp2x;
                placeholder = j;
            }
            // if y coordinate is the same as previous and the x coordinate diff
            // is smaller than the previous, set current position for closer distance
            else if ( temp2y == temp1y && temp2x < temp1x )
            {
                temp1y = temp2y;
                temp1x = temp2x;
                placeholder = j;
            }
        }

        // swap the values
        if( i + 1 != placeholder && i < total_coor - 1 )
            coor[i + 1].swap(coor[placeholder]);
    }
    // push the sorted coordinates in the list
    testcases.push_back( coor );

    //ignore blank line for each test case as instructed.
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}

// get minimum total distance from each test case.
for (std::list< std::vector< std::pair<double, double> > >::iterator itr = testcases.begin(); itr != testcases.end(); itr++ )
{
    double total = 0.0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < (*itr).size() - 1; i++ )
    {
        total += distance( (*itr)[i].first, (*itr)[i].second, (*itr)[i + 1].first, (*itr)[i + 1].second );
    }
    std::cout << std::setprecision(3);
    std::cout << total << std::endl << std::endl;
}

}

double distance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
{
// Calculating distance
    return std::sqrt( std::pow( x2 - x1, 2 ) + std::pow( y2 - y1, 2 ) );
}
```

Comment: This is a standard graph theory problem with multiple known, efficient algorithms.  You’re supposed to recognize it from the fanciful description.